# What is the difference between linear perceptron regression and LS linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Recently, a project I'm involved in made use of [a linear perceptron](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron) for multiple (21 predictor) regression. It used stochastic GD. How is this different from OLS linear regression?

Comment: The `Perceptron` class you link to is for a classifier (binary output) rather than a regressor (continuous output). Is that the actual code you used? If so, that's the difference. :)

Comment: @Dougal, it still counts among the GLMs though: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning

Comment: @Dougal: suppose you had a (G)LM that you optimized to L2 using [`SGDRegressor`](http://goo.gl/QmI6bM); would this be equivalent to linear regression?

Comment: Yes, some GLMs are classifiers. If you used `SGDRegressor(loss='squared_loss', penalty='none')`, that is OLS.

Answer (score 9):

scikit-learn's `Perceptron` class (equivalent to `SGDClassifier(loss="perceptron", penalty=None, learning_rate="constant", eta0=1)`) uses the following objective function:
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \max(0, - y_i w^T x_i).$$
In this case, $y_i \in \{-1, 1\}$. If $w^T x_i$ has the right sign, it doesn't incur any loss; otherwise, it gives linear loss. The perceptron in particular uses a fixed learning rate which can lead to some optimization weirdness as well.

Least squares regression, by contrast, uses
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - w^T x_i)^2.$$
Here $y_i$ can be any real; you can give it classification targets in $\{-1, 1\}$ if you want, but it's not going to give you a very good model.
You can optimize this with `SGDRegressor(loss="squared_loss", penalty=None)` if you'd like.

The two define fundamentally different models: the perceptron predicts a binary class label with $\mathrm{sign}(w^T x_i)$, whereas linear regression predicts a real value with $w^T x_i$. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22382/9964) talks some about why trying to solve a classification problem with a regression algorithm can be problematic.