# For a numerical outcome, is thresholding first and classification the same as regression and thresholding after the prediction?

Tags: regression, classification, predictive-models, threshold

Assuming we wanted not to predict someone's income but rather simply if that person makes more or less than a given amount (say $50k). (When) would it be better to approach this as a classification problem ("0=less than 50k, 1=more than 50k") or as regression problem? That is, would it make more sense to bin the income and then perform a classification, or perform a regression and bin the result?

There has been a question about whether every classification problem can be approached as a regression problem ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22381/127417)). I'd be interested if the answer is the same for this special case.

Comment: Setup validation and try both. I'd suspect the regression problem will do better. In general throwing away information via thresholding isn't good unless it somehow removes irrelevant noise.