# What assumptions of linear regression are violated if we use linear regression with threshold for classifiction?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I have read through the topic and have seen two major factors:-

1. I have seen the intuition around [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22381/why-not-approach-classification-through-regression)  and sort of understand it

However, I keep seeing two other points which are mentioned [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-threshold-along-with-linear-regression-for-a-classifier).

2. The error term in ordinary least squares regression is assumed to be normally distributed for the sake of inference. With a binary dependent variable, the error term won't be normally distributed. Instead, it follows the Bernoulli distribution. **Can someone please explain why the error in such a case would follow a Bernoulli distribution?**
3. Without going into the details, the assumption that the error term has constant variance also breaks. The error term becomes heteroscedastic. **Can someone please explain this as well. Why would the error term become heteroscedastic?**

Comment: The first claim (2.) is wrong. The error term of threshold OLS can e.g. also be negative, so it can't be Bernoulli.

Comment: I thought so too. Can you please explain the second point? That sort of looks valid but cant exactly create an intuition around the same.